# Toggle in react for multiple buttons

Tags: reactjs, button, toggle

`Onclick` function execute the `myChangeHandler`, which changes the state to opposite on every click. This will toggle the content inside h1 element. Here the function execute the change for both button. Any possibility to change that behaviour for individual button?

```
  class File extends React.Component {
              constructor(props) {
              super(props);
               this.state = {
               user: false,
               admin:false
            };
        
        this.myChangeHandler = this.myChangeHandler.bind(this);
      }
    
      myChangeHandler() {
        this.setState(state => ({
        user:!state.user
        admin:!state.admin
        }));
       }
        
        render() {
          return(
            <div>  <button onClick={this.myChangeHandler}>Toggle admin </button>
                 {this.state.display && <h1>admin online!</h1>} </div>
        
            <div>  <button onClick={this.myChangeHandler}>Toggle user </button>
                 {this.state.display && <h1>user online!</h1>} </div>
        )
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the buttons a `name` and access those in the handler:

```
<button name='admin' onClick={this.myChangeHandler}>Toggle admin </button>
```

```
  myChangeHandler(e) {
    const id = e.target.name
    this.setState((state) => ({
      [id]: !state[id]
    }));
  }
```

Note that you have to save the id before the setState, because setState is async and the event will be removed after the function. So if you try to access the event during the delayed setState, the name would be null.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/App.js:537-611)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference to the function to tell which button you clicked on:

```js
myChangeHandler(name) {
  this.setState((prev) => ({ [name]: !prev[name] }));
}
        
render() {
 return(
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => this.myChangeHandler('admin')}>Toggle admin </button>
     {this.state.display && <h1>admin online!</h1>}
  </div>
        
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => this.myChangeHandler('user')}>Toggle user</button>
    {this.state.display && <h1>user online!</h1>}
  </div>
 )
}
```